# Determine if an Object is infront of the Camera or Behind it?

Tags: geometry-nodes, camera, simulation-nodes

Is there a way in Blender (3.6.5, preferably Geo Nodes, but I'm okay with drivers or scripts as well) to figure out whether an object is behind the camera (so as to stop doing geo nodes animations and other processing on it).

I only want to process/simulate objects while they're in front of the camera.

What would be the simplest solution to this?

Comment: I think you're looking for frustum culling, there are tutorials

Comment: also you can search for "camera culling"